# BASH regex matching in if statement

Tags: regex, arrays, bash, if-statement

I would like to mention now that I am not overly fluent with either RegEx or BASH, so an in-deph explanation would be greatly appreciated, this way I can learn. Thanks.

I have greatly dulled down this file, but basically what I am wanting to do is take an array `$sqldatabases` and check to see which variables contain the @ symbol, then update that particular variable to not include the @ symbol, and finally run a `mysqldump` for that database. Basically what I see occurring with the code currently is the lack of the `if` statement filtering forum@.

```
source config.sh
sqldatabases=(bans forum@ users donators)
for (( sqlcount = 0; sqlcount < ${#sqldatabases[@]}; sqlcount++ ))
    do
        if [[ "$sqldatabases[sqlcount]" =~ *[@]* ]] ; then
            sqldatabases[sqlcount]=${sqldatabases[sqlcount]//[@]/}
            echo "$sqldatabases[sqlcount]"
            mysqldump -u"$sqluser" -p"$sqlpass" -h"$sqlhost" ${sqldatabases[sqlcount]} > .backups/$timedate/MySQL/${sqldatabases[sqlcount]}.sql;
        fi
    done
```

Thank you again for your assistance, and do try to explain each modification in depth.

Comment: `*[@]*` is a pattern, not a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `${array[index]}` syntax. And you do not need the `*`s to match the `@` (or use `.*@.*` instead):

```
if [[ "${sqldatabases[sqlcount]}" =~ @ ]] ; then
            sqldatabases[sqlcount]=${sqldatabases[sqlcount]//[@]/}
            echo "${sqldatabases[sqlcount]}"
            mysqldump # ...
fi
```

Comment: *facepalm* amateur mistake :p Thanks, I would have spent hours trying to figure that one out.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you do not need any loop to remove the @:

```
sqldatabases=(bans forum@ users donators)
sqldatabases=(${sqldatabases[@]/@/})
echo ${sqldatabases[*]}
```